# jquery will not call pagemethods

Tags: jquery, pagemethods

I want jquery to successfully return the result of a call to a pagemethod. I have copied each example, letter for letter, and pasted it into my web project to no avail.

I have tried examples on both VS 2005 & 2008 - nothing works. I tried the example above - nada. What am I overlooking?

Comment: Have you downloaded and included the jQuery library?

Comment: i think you are going to have to give us something to go on here.  can you post some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps, but some time ago I had problems calling PageMethods from FireFox (3.5 beta) when the Firebug add-on was enabled. With Firebug disabled, it worked.

Since then there was an update of Firebug and Firefox and now it works.